# How to Trim Audio File From Specified portion in iphone

Tags: ios

```
float vocalStartMarker = 1.0;
    float vocalEndMarker = 3.0;
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSURL *audioFileInput =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/idea_honey_bunny.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];



       NSURL *audioFileOutput =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/idea_honey_bunny.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSError *error;

    if (!audioFileInput || !audioFileOutput)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:audioFileOutput error:NULL];
    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:audioFileInput];

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset
                                                                            presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

    if (exportSession == nil)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake((int)(floor(vocalStartMarker * 1)), 1);
    CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMake((int)(ceil(vocalEndMarker * 1)), 1);
    CMTimeRange exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime);

    exportSession.outputURL = audioFileOutput;
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
    exportSession.timeRange = exportTimeRange;

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
     {
         if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status)
         {
             NSLog(@"It worked!");
         }
         else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status)
         {
             // It failed...
         }
     }];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileOutput error:&error];
    //  audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

    if (audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    else
        [audioPlayer play];
    return YES;
}
```

i want to try trimming audio file but compiler not entered in this if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status)
             {
                 NSLog(@"It worked!");
             }
             else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status)
             {
                 // It failed...
             }
         }]; bloock and file not trim

Comment: check this [link](https://github.com/romaonthego/RETrimControl)

Answer (score 0):

You have given same path for audioFileOutput and audioFileInput...So it is going into fail case.And also make sure that file is existed at input path...please change the OutputFile path and check..

Answer (score 0):

**exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler** method takes some time to export new asset. So you create your audio player with asset, which not ready.

Try to change your code like this

```
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^
 {
     if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status)
     {
        NSLog(@"It worked!");
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileOutput error:&error];
        if (audioPlayer == nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
        else {
            [audioPlayer play];
        }
     }
     else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status)
     {
         // It failed...
     }
 }];
```

Also, as Murali said above, change path for output file